# VS Code - git@gitlab.com: permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: angular, git, vscode, gitlab

tengo este error al momento de ejecutar cualquier cambio en el IDE de VS Code, lo raro de todo eso es que ya tengo la contraseña generada de ssh, incluso vinculada con GitLab, pero aún así no lo he podido solucionar.

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: Si tienes la llave publica registrada en github, la pregunta es si la registraste la privada para que git la use? Esto yo lo hago con `ssh-add la-llave-privada`. Una vez que hagas esto exitosamente, deberías poder hacer operaciones contra el repositorio de github.